# using minus numbers with rand() function? or alternative method

Tags: php

I have encountered a logical hurdle!

I have a page with 6 actions on. when you click an action, it simply returns a true or false.

Each action has its own chance of success, and the true /false is based on whether a random generated number is higher or lower than the actions success value.

the chance values are stored in the database like:  **10-20-30-40-50-60**

I call these values using explode and insert them using implode.

What I want to achieve is to change these chances values to either 1 more, 1 less or the same (upto a max of 65), each time an action is clicked and the form submitted,

This is what I have attempted but to no avail.

```
<?PHP

//CHANCE 0 (action 1)

if ($chance[0] = 0 ){ 
    $chance[0] = rand(0,1); 

    }elseif ($chance[0] = 1 ){
             $chance[0] = rand(1,2); 

    }elseif ($chance[0] >= 2 ){
             $chance[0] = $chance[0] + rand(-1,1) ; 

    }elseif ($chance[0] >= 65 ){
             $chance[0] = 65;
    }

//CHANCE 1 (action 2)

if ($chance[1] = 0 ){ 
    $chance[1] = rand(0,1); 

    }elseif ($chance[1] = 1 ){
             $chance[1] = rand(1,2); 

    }elseif ($chance[1] >= 2 ){
             $chance[1] = $chance[0] + rand(-1,1) ; 

    }elseif ($chance[1] >= 65 ){
             $chance[1] = 65;
    }
```

etc.. for all chance[0] to chance[5]

then,

```
$chancearray = array($chance[0], $chance[1], $chance[2], $chance[3], $chance[4], $chance[5]);

$newchancearray = implode("-",$chancearray);

?>
```

and insert it into the database.

can anyone help me with the logic for adding -1, 0 or 1 to the chance values after submitting the form?

at the moment its changing all values to 2 ??

so if chance was 10-20-30-40-50-60, once submitted, it becomes 2-2-2-2-2-2.

help? :(

Comment: First of all your if statements  are wrong. They are actually assignments. If needs double ==

Comment: sigh.

changed the ifs to == and it works fine. Ive spent to long on this. I think i need a break..

Thanks for your help.

im assuming the >= doesnt need changing? just the equals 1 or equals 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the = to == at the boolean expressions used on IF's

instead of

```
if ($chance[1] = 0 ){
```

should be

```
if ($chance[1] == 0 ){
```

Answer (score -1):

You know about "=="?

The code is wrong